# Why use a double square bracket in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing these values from a CSV file which I have read in pandas
So, my question is that why we are using a double square bracket for X values and a single square bracket for the Y values???

```
X = df[['sqft_living']]
Y = df['price']
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X,Y)
lm.score(X,Y)
```

Comment: Single brackets gives you a Series (`pd.Series`), double brackets gives you a DataFrame. The algorithm expects a DataFrame (or a matrix/array) for X and a Series (or a vector / 1d array) for y.

Comment: It needs a 2D array for `X`. The issue is that `df['sqft_living'].to_numpy()` has a shape `(N,)`, which is 1D. On the other hand, the DataFrame, `df[['sqft_living']].to_numpy()`, has shape `(N, 1)` which is a 2D structure.

Answer (score 11):

In python, `[]` returns a Pandas `series` object while the `[[]]` returns a data frame.
For the `fit()` function, it expects the X to be a data frame with 1 or more features. hence, `[[]]` are used.

Answer (score 0):

Single brackets are primarily used for column selection, boolean indexing, and row slicing in pandas. Double brackets, are typically used when you want to select multiple columns by passing a list of column names.